# Filtering a line with sed

Tags: command-line, sed

I have a file with columns of the form

```
number_number  number  columns of numbers
```

I want to extract the columns beginning with particular numbers. I tried the following, but get nothing in output:

```
sed -n 's/14_90 2275.*/&/p'
```

What is wrong with my command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use `grep` which is the right tool for your case? Here is an example to list the files which starts with `14_90 2275`:

```
grep '^14_90 2275' filename
```

If you still want to use `sed`, than the right command is:

```
sed -n '/^14_90 2275/p' filename
```

If the white spaces are tabs, then you should use:

```
grep $'^14_90\t2275' filename
```

respectively:

```
sed -n '/^14_90\t2275/p' filename
```

Or better:

```
grep $'^14_90\s2275' filename
```

respectively:

```
sed -n '/^14_90\s2275/p' filename
```

to match any whitespace characters (space, tab etc.).

Comment: Thanks for your example. In fact, I am reading a tutorial on sed and would like to train using it...

Comment: I just tried this command (with grep )and it doesn't output anything... The columns are separated by tabs but I tried adding a \t and it didn't work neither

Comment: @bigTree I edited my answer to see how you can match any whitespace characters (space, tab etc.).